# Viewing simple MAMP site via LAN on iPhone, iPad or other device on network

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, mamp, lan

I have MAMP set up on my iMac - just the default installation and I have my site sitting in the htdocs folder - so on my iMac, it all works as expected. I can go to `http://localhost:8888/` and I see the site.

When I used to use a Windows machine to develop (and WAMP) I could then use my iPhone, iPad or any other device on the same network to view the site in a browser by typing in the IP address of the machine it was being developed on, e.g. `http://192.168.1.15` - this made testing much simpler.

I have tried to do this with my current setup - but for some reason it won't show the site.

I'm using `http://192.168.1.15:8888` - which is my iMacš internal IP address. But no dice.

Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

In my httpd.conf file it has:

```
Listen 8888
```

And further down:

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I presumed this was all OK to allow incoming connections.

Edit: I don't have my firewall enabled either, so it's not that.

Comment: Does it work going to the IP address version on the computer itself? If not it's only listening on localhost. Maybe try `Listen 192.168.1.15:8888` (that might stop `localhost` working).

Comment: So, I got to the bottom of this.

it turns out it wasn't a problem with MAMP or my machine's setup - it was a network blunder on my behalf, so ultimately it worked as I expected from the start - and I had missed something vital!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't doing anything wrong here - and this is how it should work.

MAMP (not requiring Pro) performs this fine, and it's just a case of making sure all devices are on the same network.

I had some router issues a few weeks back, which I finally managed to solve today which led this to also end up being sorted.

Non existent problem, solved!